# How to connect RDS from a different account with allowed IP in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, ip, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance in AWS account A. Its Private IPv4 addresses is 10.111.12.23.

I allowed it in a RDS security group rules in account B, to make Type `CIDR/IP - Inbound`'s Rule `10.111.12.23/32`.
Also use transit gateway between these 2 accounts' vpc network, route them to let ec2 from account A to access account B.

When I login to ec2 in account A, can't ping the RDS cluster's endpoint. Check ip on the ec2 host, got

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:b2:31:d0:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.111.12.23/27 brd 10.111.12.43 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 2390sec preferred_lft 2390sec
    inet6 ze20::202:b3fa:fe31:a0c2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:ed:6d:80:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ze20::20:b1fa:fl39:712x/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

The IP `10.111.12.23/27`'s subnet is 27 but not 32. So is it the reason can't access the RDS, even it allowed IP with /32 but doesn't work.

And, a little much complex, I also want to access RDS in account B from account A' ec2 instance with docker on it. Login docker container, check its IP:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
117: eth0@if118: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 01:12:lc:22:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.18.0.5/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

It's using the different network IP. So even can connect RDS from ec2 host, can it also access RDS inside docker on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can't ping the RDS cluster's endpoint

RDS typically doesn't respond to *ping*. Try to connect to it with your mysql or postgresql or whatever client right away without pinging.

Also make sure that all your routing is in order - that both VPCs have routes to the other VPCs through the TGW. The packets must find a way to go from EC2->TGW->RDS and also back from RDS->TGW->EC2.

Unless you have some other uses for TGW you may be better off with a simple **VPC Peering** for your usecase.

That `/27` vs `/32` doesn't matter. One is the subnet range and one is the host IP. In the RDS SG it's enough to allow the host IP.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested with a db client to connect to RDS, it works! So the IP range doesn't matter and network setting also works. Use `VPC Peering` also work but doesn't it traffic with slow speed?

Comment: @Miantian Nope, VPC Peering is the same speed but free (+ data transfer charges same as with TGW)

Comment: By the way, do you know if there is some trouble during the connection, how to debug the transit gateway network layer? Use `AWS/TransitGateway` with CloudWatch in AWS? But from my end its disable now. I tested most connection successful, but only one failed: `psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out. Is the server running on host "xxx-rds.amazonaws.com" (10.121.10.30) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`. It's in an another account so I think the TGW not work between EC2 and its RDS.

Comment: @Miantian you can enable *VPC Flow Logs* on all interfaces in all VPCs and try to correlate where do the packets get lost. It’s usually quite a laborious work though. In cases like that I sometimes spin up another EC2 instance in the same subnet and same sec group as the RDS and use `tcpdump` on both EC2s to debug the traffic issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good methods! I will try.